# ngx-translate - No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ngx-translate

I'm very new to ionic 3 and Angular 4. I'm trying to translate a page
but when I run the app I get this error. I added the libraries and imported everything as the documentation said, and I added the translate service in the providers array in app module, but I still get this error

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, 
    TranslateService

  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild,Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild("myNav") nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon: string}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              public statusBar: StatusBar,
              public splashScreen: SplashScreen ,
              public translate: TranslateService) {

    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't 
    // found in the current language
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');

    platform.ready().then(() => {
       // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
       // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
       statusBar.styleDefault();
       splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  switchLanguage(language: string){
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage{

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private navParams: NavParams){}

}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage} from './home';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

I also added folder and 2 json files in "assets/i18n/".
please need help !!

Comment: Does the app works without ngx-translate ?

Comment: @AlexBeugnet yes

Comment: Do you have a minimal github repo to reproduce it?

Comment: What versions are you using ? I can see this from their official documentation : `if you're still on Angular <4.3, please use Http from @angular/http with http-loader@0.1.0.`

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/162698) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Rob I edited my question, by the way thanks for this advice

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I done that before but it keeps tells me that

Typescript Error
Argument of type 'Http' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpClient'. Property 'handler' is missing in type 'Http'.

Comment: Can you try removing everything from the component side ? Does the app works if you just import the TranslateModule with the HttpLoader ? In the component side, just inject the TranslateService, but do not use it. Do you have the same error ?

Comment: @AlexBeugnet the problem here is in the return line the createTranslateLoader function http parameter

`export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}`

Comment: Then is has to be something with the http-loader library or angular Http. I can't really know what it is, but it is coming from one of them. Try asking in the ngx-translate issues.

Comment: are you link (npm link) some libraries?
I have exactly the same issue but only when I link them together. As soon as I install them normally via npm everything works.
So far I have no idea what exactly causes the issue.

Comment: @Arikael no that is not my problem, what I faced here is because I installed http loader latest version and my angular is < 4.3 thanks to Alex Beugnet he told me this. I was dumb when I noticed that :) and also I used HttpClientModule, HttpClient though I was supposed to use HttpModule, and Http that's what causing me error.. I will post this in answer to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For angular version < 4.3 requires installing this version **http-loader@0.1.0** of http-loader

1) `npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader@0.1.0 --save`

2) `npm install @ngx-translate/core --save`

3) Import HttpModule and Http from @angular/http

4) Import TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService from @ngx-translate/core

5) Import TranslateHttpLoader from @ngx-translate/http-loader

6) Export function in **app.module.ts** with parameter Http

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

Here's what solves the issue in the function's parameter because I was using the latest version of http-loader, and I call httpClientModule & HttpClient, and it is not compatible with angular old version.

7) Last but not the least initialize object in constructor calling the service **TranslateService**

```
public constructor(public translate: TranslateService){

}
```

8) Finally you can use this object which you initialize it in constructor in the 
   view(html page) like this:

```
 {{'HOME.HELLO' | translate }}
```

**Note:** In json file the string (key & value) must be all capitalized.