# Karma and Jasmine injected service test with Angular 7 - StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[I18n -> InjectionToken TranslationsFormat]

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

This isn't a dupe of [ngx-translate - No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740037/ngx-translate-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-documenttoken)

.... or [angular5 ng test - StaticInjectorError from custom service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128781/angular5-ng-test-staticinjectorerror-from-custom-service)

... and this is a slightly different issue that doesn't help me - https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill/issues/4

---

I get the following error when I run `ngtest` using Jasmine and Karma:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[I18n -> InjectionToken TranslationsFormat]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[I18n -> InjectionToken TranslationsFormat]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TranslationsFormat!
```

I have a single test in my app, to test creation of the main data service:

**data.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';

describe('DataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DataService, I18n]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  SOME_CONSTANT = this.i18n('Translate this text');

  constructor(private i18n: I18n, private authService: AuthService) {

    ...
  }

  public serviceMethod() {
    return ...
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
declare var require: any;

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill'; // polyfill to support i18n for text in .ts files (until supported by Angular)
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LocaleService} from './services/locale.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

defineLocale('engb', enGbLocale);
defineLocale('de', deLocale);
defineLocale('es', esLocale);
defineLocale('fr', frLocale);
defineLocale('zhcn', zhCnLocale);
defineLocale('ru', ruLocale);

/*
export function localeFactory(): string {
  return LocaleDatePipe.localeId;
}
*/

export function selectedLocaleFactory(): string {
  const localeService = new LocaleService();
  return localeService.getCurrentLanguage();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers:
  [
    BsLocaleService,
    I18n,
    {
      provide: TRANSLATIONS,
      useFactory: (locale) => {
        locale = locale || 'en'; // default to english if no locale provided
        return require(`raw-loader!../locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`);
      },
      deps: [LOCALE_ID]
    },
    {
      provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT,
      useValue: 'xlf'
    },
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useFactory: selectedLocaleFactory
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmationComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';

import { BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { LocaleService } from './services/locale.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
    private localeService: LocaleService,
    private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

     ... nothing relevant
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I alter the `data.service.ts` to add a TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT import as below, I get a different error:

```
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [DataService, AuthService, I18n, ?InjectionToken TranslationsFormat?, ...]
```

---

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';
import { TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT } from '@angular/core';

describe('DataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DataService, AuthService, I18n, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([DataService, AuthService, I18n, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT], (service: DataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Comment: add TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT in providers in data.service.spec.ts

Comment: @AjayReddy - thanks, it didn't work though - please see my update at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }` as below in `spec` file:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [DataService, AuthService, I18n, 
      {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }]
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

For the answer to the OP, see the answer from @ShashankVivek. If you get a subsequent error related to `TRANSLATIONS`, you'll need this:

```
describe('DataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DataService, AuthService, I18n, 
        {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
        {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: 'xlf' }
      ]
    });
  });
```